# Create table which hold columns of another table and count values of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table temp:

```
id  sentence pcount ncount
1      -       3      5   
2      -       2      6
3      -       1      5
4      -       7      2
```

.....

I want to create table from above existing table which should get update when above table changes

```
New_temp

ind_type     Index_val
pcount         sum(pcount)
ncount         sum(ncount)
```

Is it possible? 
please tell me how this could be done.

Comment: you can use trigger for this pourpose

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new table.  Just create a view:

```
create view new_temp
    select 'pcount' as ind_type, sum(pcount) as thecount
    from temp union all
    select 'ncount', sum(ncount)
    from temp;
```

Only create a new table if you really need to for performance reasons.

If you do create a new table, then you have to also write triggers for the `temp` table when values change (`insert`, `update`, `delete`).  A view is much simpler.

EDIT:

Oh, I misunderstood the format for the table you want.  You want one row with two columns.  That is even easier:

```
create view new_temp
    select sum(pcount) as pcount, sum(ncount) as ncount
    from temp;
```

Comment: Does MySQL have persisted views?  Such as by creating an index on them?  As otherwise there may be a large computational overhead when reading if those reads outweigh the rate of change in the source table.

Comment: @Gordon: My intension is to use this data to create the Pie chart. I want when user click on show chart button this table get created on fly which is used to create the Pie chart!

Comment: @Gordon: Can view be used in same manner in replace of table?

Comment: @Karimkhan . . . Yes it can.  The difference is performance.  The view redoes the calculation every time it is called, instead of storing the data directly.  If you are working with a small'ish data set (say up to 100,000 rows or even more), then the view should be fine.  Focus on performance after you have everything else working.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks, it gives result with two column `(ind_type,sum(pcount))`. Column 1 contains values (1,2) and col2 (27,28). How can I have (pcount,ncount) in place of (1,2)! Your post is about to complete my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Trigger should solve your problem

```
Create trigger trgtemp
after update on temp for each row
insert into newtemp (ind_type,pcount,ncount)
values (@param1,@param2,@param3)
```